# /* in transcoding from HTTP to gRPC

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, transcoding

```
rpc CreateBook(CreateBookRequest) returns (Book) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
    post: "/v1/{parent=publishers/*}/books"
    body: "book"
  };
}

message CreateBookRequest {
  // The publisher who will publish this book.
  // When using HTTP/JSON, this field is automatically populated based
  // on the URI, because of the `{parent=publishers/*}` syntax.
  string parent = 1 [
    (google.api.field_behavior) = REQUIRED,
    (google.api.resource_reference) = {
      child_type: "library.googleapis.com/Book"
    }];

  Book book = 2 [(google.api.field_behavior) = REQUIRED];

  string book_id = 3;
}
```

I don't understand `post: "/v1/{parent=publishers/*}/books"`

I thought `publishers` was a field in `CreateBookRequest`, then it populates to `http`, so it is something like this
`post: "/v1/parent=publishers_field_value/books"`

But `publishers` is not a field in `CreateBookRequest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `publishers` is part of the expected *value* of the `parent` field. So suppose you have a protobuf request like this:

```json
{
  "parent": "publishers/pub1",
  "book_id": "xyz"
  "book": {
    "author": "Stacy"
  }
}
```

That can be transcoded by a client into an HTTP request with:

- Method: POST
- URI: `/v1/publishers/pub1/books?bookId=xyz` (with the appropriate host name)
- Body:

  ```json
  {
    "author": "Stacy"
  }
  ```

If you try to specify a request with a `parent` that *doesn't* match `publishers/*`, I'd expect transcoding to fail.

That's in terms of transcoding from protobuf to HTTP, in the request. (That's the direction I'm most familiar with, having been coding it in C# just this week...)

In the *server*, it should just be the opposite - so given the HTTP request above, the server should come up with the original protobuf request including `parent="publishers/pub1"`.

For a lot more information on all of this, see the [proto defining HttpRule](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto).